# how to check if there exists a unique shortest path between two vertices in igraph

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, shortest-path

I'd like to identify if there exist a unique shortest path or multiple shortest paths between two vertices with igraph. If I use `length(all_shortest_paths(g, i,j)`, that actually helps me, but I feel like there are so many redundant operations. I rather prefer first to get one shortest path with `get.shortest.paths(g, i,j)`, and then see if there is another. However, I could not figure out how to do this.

Can someone help me how to identify whether there is another shortest path different than the first one obtained by `get.shortest.paths(g, i,j)`?

Here is an example graph

```
library(igraph)
data <- read.table(text="
1 2
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
3 4
5 7
5 8
3 6", header=FALSE)
gmatrix <- data.matrix(data, rownames.force = NA) #convert into a matrix to use in igraph
g <- graph_from_edgelist(gmatrix, directed = FALSE)
```

For instance, if I'd like to find the shortest path from 1 to 3, I use `all_shortest_paths(g, 1,3)`, and it gives me the following result.

```
$res
$res[[1]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from 634c426:
[1] 1 4 3

$res[[2]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from 634c426:
[1] 1 2 3
```

What I want is to get the first shortest path. For instance

```
get.shortest.paths(g, 1,3)
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from 634c426:
[1] 1 2 3
```

Now, I want to see if there is any other path different than `[1] 1 2 3`. In a larger graph, since there are tens of possible shortest paths, I don't want to use `all_shortest_paths(g, i,j)` to make that query.

Overall, my question is: how can I check whether there exists a  unique shortest path between two vertices or not? I will give two vertices as my input, in return I should get TRUE or FALSE indicating if there is a unique shortest path.

Comment: what do you want returned? The particular vertex sequence? T or F indicating if there is more than one shortest path? The number of shortest paths?

Comment: @paqmo I only need true or false, whether there exists a unique path or not.

Comment: @paqmo I left a comment under your answer, however, I could not find a way to tag your user name there. I'd really appreciate, if you could answer my question.

Comment: got it. i misunderstood. how about `length(all_shortest_paths(g, 1,3)$res) > 1`?

Comment: That does not run in polynomial time. It takes forever to solve this problem for a large -scale graph if I use ```length(all_shortest_paths(g, i,j)```. I don't need to find all of them.  In fact, identifying one extra path should be enough for me.

Comment: i wonder if there is some way to do this using `bfs` or `dfs` using a callback function.

Comment: I am currently working on this. My initial thought is the following; (1) use get.shortest.paths(g, 1,3) without any edge weight. (2) assign a non-negative epsilon on the edges used in that specific path. (3) call again get.shortest.paths with Dijkstras. (4) Then, compare those two paths. If they are the same, then the path is unique. Now, I need to figure out how to assign edge weights on specific edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting responded for [How to assign edge weights to certain edges in R igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577735/how-to-assign-edge-weights-to-certain-edges-in-r-igraph), here is one solution. Please note that the initial network is an undirected graph with no edge weights.

```
p <- get.shortest.paths(g, i, j)$vpath[[1]] #shortest path between node i and node j
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value = ifelse(E(g) %in% E(g, path = p), 1.50, 1)) #Assign slightly larger edge weights to the edges existing in path p
q <- get.shortest.paths(g, i,j , weights = E(g)$weight)$vpath[[1]] #recalculate the shortest path with edge weights
g <- delete_edge_attr(g, "weight")
if(all(p %in% q))
#If paths p and q are the same, then the shortest path is unique
```

However, this is definitely not a good solution due to the high running time. When I try this method for 400 nodes, it takes several minutes to stop.