# How to assign edge weights to certain edges in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I'd like to assign a small, non-negative edge weights to certain edges used in a shortest path. Here is an example graph:

```
library(igraph)
data <- read.table(text="
1 2
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
3 4
5 7
5 8
3 6", header=FALSE)
gmatrix <- data.matrix(data, rownames.force = NA) #convert into a matrix to use in igraph
g <- graph_from_edgelist(gmatrix, directed = FALSE)
```

If I find the shortest path between node 1 and node 3, the edges used are 1-2 and 1-3.

```
get.shortest.paths(g, 1,3)
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 3/9 vertices, from 634c426:
[1] 1 2 3
```

What I want to do is to assign a small epsilon value to those edges. Then, I'd like to call `get.shortest.paths(g, 1,3)` to test whether the function will identify the same path or not.

Comment: What do you mean by *to extract these two edges*? To extract the end points of the path and assign a `weight` to them?

Comment: I meant the edges used in the shortest path. Suppose my shortest path is (3-7-9-4). Then, I want to assign edge weights to (3-7) / (7-9) / (9-4). Let me rephrase it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this I can help with:

Use `E()` to query the edges with the ids grabbed from `get.shortest.paths` and assign the values to a new edge attribute name (e.g., "weight" or whatever):

```
p <- get.shortest.paths(g, 1, 3)$vpath[[1]]

E(g, path = p)$weight <- 0.1
```

#### Check the result:

```
> E(g)
+ 9/9 edges from 605e8c7:
[1] 1--2 1--4 1--5 2--3 2--4 3--4 5--7 5--8 3--6
> E(g)$weight
[1] 0.1  NA  NA 0.1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

The path from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 now has a weighted edge.

Now, assign zero to the other edges and 'get.shortest.paths` identifies another path:

```
> E(g)$weight <- ifelse(is.na(E(g)$weight), 0, E(g)$weight)
> E(g)$weight
[1] 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
> get.shortest.paths(g, 1, 3, weights = E(g)$weight)
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from 605e8c7:
[1] 1 4 3


$epath
NULL

$predecessors
NULL

$inbound_edges
NULL
```

A bit more concise:

```
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value = ifelse(E(g) %in% E(g, path = p), 0.1, 0))

E(g)$weight
[1] 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Just a quick question, how do you compare two paths to see if they are identical? I used ```length(difference(p,q)``` where p is the original shortest path and q is the next one identified after updating the edges. I was wondering if there's a better way to do so?

Comment: maybe `all(p %in% q)`?

Comment: Great! Thanks. One last question is do you know how to delete the edge weight attributes? I am trying to use what suggested here at https://rdrr.io/cran/igraph/man/delete_edge_attr.html , but could not get it done.

Comment: either `E(g)$weight <- NULL` or `g <- delete_edge_attr(g, “weight”)` should do it

Answer (score 1):

In the code that follows I will use function `all_shortest_paths`, not `get.shortest.paths`, to get all shortest paths. This is because I will later assign weights to the edges of one of them.

The paths asked are between vertices `3` and `5`, since there are two paths.

First, see what `get.shortest.paths` returns.

```
get.shortest.paths(g, 3, 5)
#$vpath
#$vpath[[1]]
#+ 4/8 vertices, from 98e8e26:
#[1] 3 2 1 5
#
#
#$epath
#NULL
#
#$predecessors
#NULL
#
#$inbound_edges
#NULL
```

The function returns just one path: `3 2 1 5`. But there are two shortest paths between vertices `3` and `5`.

```
p <- all_shortest_paths(g, 3, 5)
p
#$res
#$res[[1]]
#+ 4/8 vertices, from fc330b4:
#[1] 3 2 1 5
#
#$res[[2]]
#+ 4/8 vertices, from fc330b4:
#[1] 3 4 1 5
#
#
#$nrgeo
#[1] 2 1 1 1 2 1 0 0
```

Now assign *epsilon* weights to the edges of one of the paths, the first one.

```
E(g, path = p$res[[1]])$weight <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5
E(g)$weight
#[1] 1.490116e-08           NA 1.490116e-08 1.490116e-08           NA
#[6]           NA           NA           NA           NA
```

Get all shortest paths again.

```
all_shortest_paths(g, 3, 5)
#$res
#$res[[1]]
#+ 4/8 vertices, from fc330b4:
#[1] 3 4 1 5
#
#
#$nrgeo
#[1] 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Only one path now, path `3 4 1 5`, former path `p$res[[1]]` is now heavier, no longer a shortest path.

And `get.shortest.paths` also returns the one path.

```
get.shortest.paths(g, 3, 5)
#$vpath
#$vpath[[1]]
#+ 4/8 vertices, from 98e8e26:
#[1] 3 4 1 5
#
#
#$epath
#NULL
#
#$predecessors
#NULL
#
#$inbound_edges
#NULL
```

**EDIT.**

Following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577735/how-to-assign-edge-weights-to-certain-edges-in-r-igraph/57578348#comment101617100_57578348) by user [paqmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4488105/paqmo), the following code uses only function `get.shortest.paths` to get *a* shortest path. After assigning weights to its edges, the path returned by the same function is no longer `p2`, it's the same as in the code above.

This code only makes sense if the graph is reinitialized with no weights attribute.

```
p2 <- get.shortest.paths(g, 3, 5)
p2
#$vpath
#$vpath[[1]]
#+ 4/8 vertices, from 61bfc89:
#[1] 3 2 1 5
#
#
#$epath
#NULL
#
#$predecessors
#NULL
#
#$inbound_edges
#NULL


E(g, path = p2$vpath[[1]])$weight <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5
E(g)$weight
get.shortest.paths(g, 3, 5)
#$vpath
#$vpath[[1]]
#+ 4/8 vertices, from 61bfc89:
#[1] 3 4 1 5
#
#
#$epath
#NULL
#
#$predecessors
#NULL
#
#$inbound_edges
#NULL
```

Comment: unclear in this question, but op specifically wants to call `get.shortest.paths` rather than `all_shortest_paths` since they are trying to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529808/how-to-check-if-there-exists-a-unique-shortest-path-between-two-vertices-in-igra)