# Shortest path function returns a wrong path in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I use `get.shortest.paths` method to find the shortest path between two vertices. However, something odd is happening. After the comment that I received, I am changing the entire question body. I produced my graph with `g <- sample_smallworld(1, 20, 5, 0.1)` and here is the adjacency list.

```
*Vertices 20
*Edges
1 2 0
2 3 0
3 4 0
4 5 0
5 6 0
6 7 0
7 8 0
8 9 0
9 10 0
10 11 0
11 12 0
12 13 0
13 14 0
14 15 0
6 15 0
16 17 0
17 18 0
18 19 0
19 20 0
1 20 0
1 11 0
1 19 0
1 4 0
1 18 0
1 5 0
1 17 0
6 17 0
15 16 0
2 20 0
2 4 0
2 19 0
2 5 0
2 18 0
2 9 0
2 17 0
2 13 0
3 5 0
3 20 0
3 6 0
3 19 0
3 7 0
3 18 0
3 8 0
4 6 0
4 7 0
4 20 0
4 8 0
5 19 0
4 9 0
5 7 0
5 8 0
5 9 0
5 20 0
5 10 0
6 8 0
6 9 0
6 10 0
6 11 0
7 9 0
7 10 0
7 11 0
7 12 0
1 10 0
8 11 0
1 12 0
8 13 0
9 11 0
9 12 0
9 13 0
7 14 0
12 19 0
10 13 0
10 14 0
10 15 0
11 13 0
11 14 0
11 15 0
4 16 0
12 14 0
9 15 0
12 16 0
12 17 0
13 15 0
13 16 0
13 17 0
13 18 0
14 16 0
14 17 0
14 18 0
14 19 0
15 17 0
15 18 0
15 19 0
1 15 0
16 18 0
16 19 0
9 20 0
17 19 0
17 20 0
10 18 0
```

The shortest path reported between 7 and 2 is:

```
> get.shortest.paths(g,7,2)
$vpath
$vpath[[1]]
+ 4/20 vertices, from c915453:
[1]  7 14 19  2
```

Here is the adjacent nodes to node 7 and node 2:

```
> unlist(neighborhood(g, 1, 7, mode="out")) 
 [1]  7  3  4  5  6  8  9 10 11 12 14
> unlist(neighborhood(g, 1, 2, mode="out")) 
 [1]  2  1  3  4  5  9 13 17 18 19 20
```

As you can see, I can go from 7 to 3 and from 3 to 2. It looks like there is a shorter path. What could I be missing?

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is not reproducible. `sample_smallworld` has a random component to it and you did not set the random.seed before running it, so we cannot get exactly the same graph as you had.  Neither can _you_.  It is also a bit odd that you are computing neighbors using `mode="out"` on an undirected graph.

Comment: @G5W Okay, I am now sharing the adjacency list produced by ```sample_smallworld ```. I still have the same issue.

Comment: Under the limitation @G5W already mentioned: You could try setting the edge weight to 1 instead of 0 and see what happens. My guess is, that an edge weight of zero is messing with the computation and potentially leads to randomness. (Although, I could be completely wrong)

Comment: @BenNutzer That was my initial thought. In this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577735/how-to-assign-edge-weights-to-certain-edges-in-r-igraph), under the comment section, I asked how to get rid of the weights, but neither ```E(g)$weight <- NULL```, nor ```g <- delete_edge_attr(g, “weight”)``` works. I receive different errors.

Comment: `delete_edge_attr` works for me. Use one of the following quotation marks: `"weight"` or  `'weight'`, not `“weight”`.  Also overriding it with `1` works (strangely not with `NA`).

Comment: Back to your original question: I can reproduce your error using a random seed and setting the edge weight to 0. That is, when trying to calculate the shortest between *non-direct* neighbours, the calculation is off.

Comment: @BenNutzer Then, is the main issue using the edge weights of 0? Also, is simply using ```unlist(neighborhood(g, 1, i))``` enough to find the adjacent nodes in undirected graphs?

Comment: 1) That seems very likely, but I have not thoroughly tested it nor looked under the hood of the function. 2) Yes I'd say so, refer to `?neighborhood`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  the problem is your edge weights of zero.  Looking at the help page `?shortest_paths`

> weights
>   Possibly a numeric vector giving edge weights. If this is
>   NULL and the graph has a weight edge attribute, then the attribute is
>   used. If this is NA then no weights are used (even if the graph has a
>   weight attribute).

Note that `weights=NULL` is the default, so weights will be used. Therefore the weight of the path that was returned is zero -  the same as the path that you wanted to get. The *weighted* distance is the same. If you want to find the path with the smallest number of hops, turn off the use of the weights like this:

```
get.shortest.paths(g,7,2, weights=NA)$vpath
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. For some reason, if edge weights are zero, the method does something that I could not figure out. Another solution could be ```g <- delete_edge_attr(g, "weight")``` and then use ```get.shortest.paths```